# How to prevent selection of a SortableJS item when clicking on one of its child elements?

Tags: vue.js, sortablejs, multi-drag

**The Issue**

I'm using [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) to build a draggable tree component. Which means each of my `sortable-item`s has a `toggle-arrow` as a child element that opens and closes a `sub-tree` (if there is one).

I'm attempting to use `stopPropagation()` to prevent the selection of the parent `sortable-item` if the `toggle-arrow` is clicked, but it's not working.

It looks like this when closed:
[image]

And looks like this when open:
[image]

The blue highlight you see in the open state (the second image) is the styling I've chosen for the `selectedClass` option when using the `multiDrag` plugin.

This is illustrating that when I click on the `toggle-arrow` it results in the parent `sortable-item` being selected.

I don't want this to happen.

**The Code**

The code for an item in my SortableJS tree component looks like so (using Vue.js, and Pug syntax):

```
div.sortable-item
    div.content
        div.toggle-arrow(@click.stop="toggleTree($event)")
        div.icon
        div.title
    div.sub-tree
```

And then I've got a handler for the `@click` binding on my `toggle-arrow` element:

```
toggleTree = function($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation()
    /// Code for handling the sub-tree toggling goes here.
    /// The sub-tree toggling itself works just fine.
}
```

You can see that I'm declaring `@click.stop` as the event binding, which should stop the `click` event from bubbling up from the `toggle-arrow` child element, but it's not working.

I'm even attempting to use `$event.stopPropagation` within the handler. But, the event seems to continue to bubble, and thus the parent `sortable-item` element ends up in a selected state.

I've also tried declaring `@click.native.stop` as the event binding, but it simply prevents my `toggleTree` method from firing at all. I'm assuming there's another event handler somewhere within `SortableJS` that's interfering with the `@click.native.stop` binding.

**Questions**

1. How do I stop propagation of an event when a child element of my `sortable-item` is clicked?
2. How is selection handled by the `multiDrag` plugin? I dug through the code and saw that [the `select` event is fired within the handler of the `drop` event](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/blob/88838bfa5647e278f4cf87fdd4c3e34cd24fb33c/plugins/MultiDrag/MultiDrag.js#L317) of the `sortable-item`, but I'm confused by that. Why is the `drop` event handler being used to toggle selection of a `sortable-item`?

Thanks in advance for any light you may be able to shed on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Wrong Event**

Looking at the source of SortableJS it seems that the event you want to stop from bubbling is not the `click` event, but rather the `mouseup` event.

[image]

**The "Stuck" Drag Item Problem**

As indicated in the comments of this answer, stopping propagation on the `mouseup` event causes an issue where the drag is started unintentionally, and the `sortable-item` becomes "stuck" to the pointer.

It seems that the "drag initiation" is triggered by either `pointerdown`, `mousedown`, or `touchstart` events, depending on the device.

It can be safely assumed that the `pointerdown` event is the one that does the triggering [according to caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=pointerevent).

[image]

**The Solution**

So the actual way to solve this is to use a `@pointerdown.stop` event binding to trigger your `toggleTree` method without triggering either selection of the `sortable-item`, or the unintentional drag initiation.

```
div.sortable-item
    div.content
        div.toggle-arrow(@pointerdown.stop="toggleTree($event)")
        div.icon
        div.title
    div.sub-tree
```

Comment: @ 多一点点爱 Good find! I've done an initial test and this works — kinda. It does stop the propagation so that it prevents the item from ending up in a selected state. But it also initiates a drag and the item ends up "stuck" to the cursor. But, since you answered the question at-hand the bounty is yours.

Comment: Can you add where you found the lines of code in the repo please.

Comment: Figured it out. By using `@pointerdown.stop` instead it solved my problem. I've updated this answer to reflect all the info. Thanks again for your help in figuring this out. It was driving me crazy for days :P

Comment: @AJB You have added a lot of details. My English is not very good. I am glad to solve your problem.

Comment: Good job updating the answer, @AJB.

Comment: Should probably make it clearer that `pointerdown.stop` is the solution.  I read the first paragraph and though it was `mouseup`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
div.toggle-arrow(@click.stop="toggleTree($event)")
```

to

```
div.toggle-arrow(@click.native.stop="toggleTree($event)")
```

If all you did in `toggleTree` was `stopPropagation`, you could have changed it to:

```
div.toggle-arrow(@click.native.stop)
```

[Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components).

In short, you're currently stopping propagation on any emitted clicks from the child component (a.k.a. custom Vue event, which doesn't actually need propagation stopped as it doesn't bubble by default). What you want to do is call `event.stopPropagation()` on the native `click` event.
An alternative would be to use:

```
div.toggle-arrow(@click.native="toggleTree($event)")
```

... and call `.stopPropagation()` inside `toggleTree`. Which is precisely what `.stop` modifier does.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my original question that I've already tried `@click.native.stop`. I thought that would do the trick as well, but it simply stopped calling my `toggleTree` method altogether. My assumption is that there's another handler somewhere within `SortableJS` that's interfering with how `@click.native` is supposed to work. +1 for the answer though, it may help someone else.

Comment: Glad you were able to find the culprit.